# update list from another list - entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

**Room Model**

```
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

`Id` is the primary key here

As in entity framework, all the room details are in the dbcontext

```
dbContext.Rooms
```

And there is a `IList<Room> updateRooms`with list of updated name and address for few rooms.

How do I update `dbContext.Rooms` for the matching items in `updateRooms` using the primary key `Id` and save to DB using entity framework.

**Note:** I do understand that I can update each Room in dbContext.Rooms and save as below

```
foreach (var room in updateRooms)
{
    dbContext.Rooms.Attach(room);
    dbContext.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

but is there a way **attach all rooms** and save at once

Comment: dbContext.Rooms.AddRange(updateRooms); dbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar will it insert new records instead of updating only the matching records?

Comment: It'll update the records, if you have Id filled up in the IList<Room> updateRooms, else it'll insert. If you do not have Id in that IList<Room>, then the above solution will not work.

Comment: It will create new records even if you have Ids in that IList<Room>

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar No. It doesn't. I confirmed.

Comment: @TechJerk you can move  dbContext.SaveChanges(); outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For another awswer

```
    foreach (var room in updateRooms)
    {
        dbContext.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

You also use this.

Comment: updateRooms.ToList().ForEach(room => dbContext.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified);
  dbContext.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 1):

First You need to find all the entries with Id (Primary Key) and update the values. Then call SaveChanges() method.

```
foreach (var room in updateRooms)
{
    var roomToUpdate = dbContext.Rooms.Find(room.Id);
    roomToUpdate.Name = room.Name;
    roomToUpdate.Address = room.Address;
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach(var item in updateRooms)
{
var oldModel= dbContext.Rooms.First(a => a.Id == item.Id);
 if(oldModel !=null)
{
    oldModel.Name = item.Name;
    oldModel.Address = item.Address;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

}

Try This.

Comment: It will Work...Try it